# Animating (moving) ImageView works one way but not the other

Tags: android

I creating a "Add" button by using sdk, so i wan it to move it to left when i press that "Add" button, and come back to original place when i press again. The problem i have is the button only can go to the left when press, and cannot come back to the original place after i trying to press it again. Does it i having some problem on the if...else function there? any help would appreciate.

```
public class TestImage2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ImageView image_plus;
ImageView image_subtract;
ImageView image_multiply;
ImageView image_div;

String op;

boolean pergi = false;
final  Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0,0);
final  Animation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(100,0,0,0);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    image_plus     = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test_image);     
    image_subtract = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test_image2);
    image_multiply = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test_image3);
    image_div      = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test_image4);

    image_plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View view) {

                if(pergi == false)
                {

                        animation.setDuration(1000);
                        image_plus.startAnimation(animation);
                        pergi= true;

                        animation.setFillAfter(true); 
                }
                else
                {

                        animation2.setDuration(1000);
                        image_plus.startAnimation(animation2);
                        pergi = false;
                        animation2.setFillAfter(true); 
                }
                }});
```

Comment: it seems like it only can run it on the if... function, not till the else... function. Should i have to replace the "true" / "false" to others like "1"/ "0" ?

Comment: p/s : and sorry i'm still new and beginner for coding.

Comment: can you use debugger? I can teach you :) point red dot on the left of your code - let's say the line where is `public void onClick(View view)` then click debug in your JAVA IDE. Then your app will start, do what you must to do, then click the button in your app - to init your method, debug will stop on the line which you selected :) add to watch the variable by selecting variable `pergi` and clicking right mouse button on it > selecting `add to watch` then at the bottom of your JAVA IDE you will see the value of it variable. If you have IntelliJ you click F8 to forward the code..

Comment: @stevenlim: I have renamed the title of your question to make it more relevant to your problem. I've also removed the 'java' and 'eclipse' tags as this seems to be a problem related to Android animation. I don't have an answer to the question but hopefully somebody will be able to help.

Comment: @Lumma erm, im not sure how to do it but i will try it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @stevenlim: I tried to have the question re-opened but it hasn't happened. I know part of the answer to your question. When the `ImageView` moves, the area where you need to click stays the same and doesn't move with the image. Try clicking again where the image was first and you'll see the second animation will work. I'll try and find out how to move the 'click' area and get back to you.

Comment: Yea i have found out this issue just now.. it seems like the button didn't move along with the image. And when i clicking again where the image was first i can see the image move to the left. so bout the question re-opened, how to re-opened back? o.o

Comment: I doubt it will be re-opened. I flagged it for moderator attention and asked to have it re-opened but the moderators obviously didn't agree with me. I did see this question though... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604802/clickable-imageview-location-change-with-animation-android - if you look at the answer it suggests placing an empty FrameLayout (which can also have the same `OnClickListener`) or simply change the layout pameters of the `ImageView` to increase its margin to 100.

Answer (score 0):

i think that there is something wrong in

```
final  Animation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(100,0,0,0);
```

it should be

```
final  Animation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0,-100,0,0);
```

:)

Comment: It not working..the button still wont goes back. Thanks for help anyway. :)